# How to get mbstowcs_s result variable return from function

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables, void

I made a post yesterday and screwed it up a bit. I still got a great answer, I did some more work, but I remain having an issue.
**how do I get the "return_address" from mbstowcs_s into my main dir_path?**

**.h file:**

```
void* get_absolute_path(char *directory, u16 *return_address, int len);
```

**Function .c file:**

```
void* get_absolute_path(char *directory, u16 *return_address, int len) {
    u64 dest;
    int errorDir = mbstowcs_s(&dest, return_address, len, directory, len);
    return return_address;
}
```

**main, function caller:**

```
int main(void) {

    char dir[] = "C:\\Windows\\";
    u16 return_address[268];
    u16 dir_path = get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);

    return true;
}
```

I get a clang error:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [link] Error 1120
Error:2
```

---

BUT
If I remove the "*" from the void's, I get a different error:

```
error: void function 'get_absolute_path' should not return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
    return return_address;
```

But this thing is incredible unstable!
If I remove the "*" from void, run it, and than re-type the * after the voids as posted, I get a different error this time:

```
 warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
      initializing 'u16' (aka 'unsigned short') with an expression of type 'void *'
      [-Wint-conversion]
    u16 dir_path = get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);
        ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Do I run it again a 2nd time, than I get the original error again:
I restarted the pc, but this unstable error thing keeps happening.

u16 is unsigned short.
u64 is unsigned long long.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

I'm new to C and I understand the point thing on paper, in practise I have some issues with it. So I played around with making pointers at different places and so on.
I very much would like to make this work without allocating.

Adding a "*" before dir_path:

```
u16 dir_path = get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);
```

to:

```
u16 *dir_path = get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);
```

Gives the error:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [link] Error 1120
```

**u16**

Changing void* tot u16, I get the error:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning
      'u16 *' (aka 'unsigned short *') from a function with result type 'u16'
      (aka 'unsigned short'); dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    return return_address;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So adding the "*" at return,

```
return *return_address;
```

:

```
 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [link] Error 1120
Error:2
```

**u16***

Changing the void* tot u16*:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
      initializing 'u16' (aka 'unsigned short') with an expression of type 'u16 *'
      (aka 'unsigned short *'); dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    u16 dir_path = get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);
```

So as stated, now I add the "*" :

```
u16 dir_path = *get_absolute_path(dir, return_address, 268);
```

And from this I get:

```
 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [link] Error 1120
```

```
    ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `u16 dir_path` should be `u16 *dir_path`. The function returns a pointer, so you have to assign it to a pointer variable.

Comment: Why does the function even need to return anything? It modifies `return_address` in place.

Comment: @Barmar, roger that! I still get an fatal error. So I remove the return as you state (I'm still a noob in c). But same problem, error LNK2019 exit code 1120 .

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just not experiences enough. I'm note sure anymore what to do with the error codes, I don't understand it. I did what I did understand.

Comment: Link errors have nothing to do with data types.

Comment: Show your compilation command that's getting that error. It sounds like you're not linking the two files together.

Comment: @Barmar hmmm, the .h file is included in the .c counter file, and in the file with the main(void) function that calls the function. That should be it right?

Comment: @Barmar I did do a fprint test, and it all seems to connect and compile just fine. The setup is a bit expensive because it uses .bat files and makefile .mak setup. This all is a side folder in a vulkan game engine I make following Travis Vroman on YouTube with his Kohi serries

Comment: No. You have to link them together. `gcc main.c function.c -o main`

Comment: @FromLake Then start learning C from more simple programs.

Comment: @Barmar ok I'm on it. Googling now and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `u64` instead of `size_t`, and `u16` instead of `wchar_t`? And why are you returning a `void*` when the caller wants a `wchar_t*`? Making assumptions about type equivalence makes your code harder to follow and more prone to accidental bugs. Make sure you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mbstowcs-s-mbstowcs-s-l?view=msvc-170) also, as your current call allows the function to overflow your buffer.

Comment: @paddy I am makeing some adjustments in a serries I follow from Travis Vroman on youtube where we build a game engine with Vulkan in C without libraries. For this we created a defines.h where we have all these sorts and longs and everything set up. And I am doing void because this is what someone yesterday suggested.

Comment: I think you gotta get a grasp of the basics first. What I see in your question is a whole series of guesses demonstrating a complete lack of knowledge about what pointers are and how they work. This stuff is really important to have under your belt before embarking on something as complex as building a full game engine. I highly doubt that the target audience for this video series includes beginners.

Comment: Yesterday, it was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77909678/2505965) that `get_absolute_path` return a `u16 *` (*pointer-to-u16*; an allocated buffer) **OR** `void` (*nothing*; function modifies a buffer via its arguments). You have seemingly combined these pieces of advice, and have made the function return `void *` (*pointer-to-void*; a generic type).

Comment: @OKa Yeah true, I got desperate. I tried everything.

Comment: @Barmar is right, it's a linking problem. I'm not sure why and where, it did work before. But, it is a problem between linking the files. Time to play sherlock Holmes again.